# How to add base url before image path in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There are several images in my database. Some image path are set with base url and some are not. The images which are set without base url are not coming in my frontend.
I want to set base url to images which do not contain base url.
For example, if a image path is like this -
**/thumbnail/subjects/ban2b_9.png**

I want to add base url before /thumbnail.

And dont want to affect images that already contain base url.

How to do this with javascript in vue ?

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 p-0" v-for="(subjects,index) in subjectData" :key="index">
            <div class="card subject_section_card" >
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="subject_section_card_link">
                  <img :src="subjects.avatar" class="subject_section_card_icon">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where is your code? What you have tried so far?

Comment: This sounds like you should update your database so that *all* images use an absolute, root-relative, or relative URL.

Comment: Ok I am adding my code .

Comment: I understand. But I want to do it from frontend. I have added my html code. Please check.

Comment: As an aside, have you considered using the [`<base>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base), which seems like it should solve your problem (though it may well complicate other relative paths, unfortunately).

Comment: How to check if an image path contains base url ? Then I can implement the rest.

Comment: @alprazolam With pure JS, you can try `window.location.origin`. But if your vue are running as SPA, the URL should be resolved from API

Comment: Its solved. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i try to resolve this.

you just need to write a single function in method

```
getImage(url){
  // let baseurl = 'baseurl';
  if (url.match(this.baseUrl)) {
    return url;
  } else {
    return this.baseUrl + url;
  }
}
```

or modify in html

```
:src="getImage(subjects.avatar)"
```

here a working code on codepan

https://codepen.io/imnoorfahad/pen/JjMMRww

Answer (score 0):

Write the path of the image where you are storing the images and then call the image at the  end like
../storage/product/{product.image}

Comment: Question is some have base url some image have not

Comment: Exactly. Not all images are containing base url . And its very irritating to add them manually in database because there arehundreds of images.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: Here the base URL comes from the different file where you provide the database URL. For dynamic image use this `$` inside ``.

So, this is how you can provide a dynamic image from database using the src attribute in Vue.js:

```
<img
  :src="`${this.base_url}/static/${this.image}`"
  :style="{ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' }"
  class="busines-upload-button"
/>
```

Comment: I dont want to add base url before every image path.